Uneven spacing between flex items when using flexbox

NavBar.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import './NavBar.css';




function NavBar() {
  const heading = 'first heading'

  let list = ['About Us', 'Career Page', 'Resources']

  const BuildList =  () => { 
    return(
      <>
      <div className = 'nav-container'>
      <div className='logo-container'> Logo Container</div>
        <div className='nav-content-container'>
        </div>
        <div className="navbar-primary-menu">
          { list.map((key) => (<div className='navbar-primary-menu-items' key={key}> {key} </div>)) }
        </div>
      <div className="search-container">
      <svg className='search-icon' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
<path fill="#616161" d="M34.6 28.1H38.6V45.1H34.6z" transform="rotate(-45.001 36.586 36.587)"></path><path fill="#616161" d="M20 4A16 16 0 1 0 20 36A16 16 0 1 0 20 4Z"></path><path fill="#37474F" d="M36.2 32.1H40.2V44.400000000000006H36.2z" transform="rotate(-45.001 38.24 38.24)"></path><path fill="#64B5F6" d="M20 7A13 13 0 1 0 20 33A13 13 0 1 0 20 7Z"></path><path fill="#BBDEFB" d="M26.9,14.2c-1.7-2-4.2-3.2-6.9-3.2s-5.2,1.2-6.9,3.2c-0.4,0.4-0.3,1.1,0.1,1.4c0.4,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.4-0.1C16,13.9,17.9,13,20,13s4,0.9,5.4,2.5c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.4c0.2,0,0.5-0.1,0.6-0.2C27.2,15.3,27.2,14.6,26.9,14.2z"></path>
</svg>
        <input className='input-field' type='text'></input>
       </div>
      </div> 
      </>
    );
  };
  // const element = <ul> <li>Hello there</li></ul>

  return(
    <div>
      <BuildList/>
    </div>
  );
}


export default NavBar

NavBar.css
.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  background: cyan;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  
  width: 100%;
  gap: 10px
}

.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 10px solid yellow;

}

li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 10px  solid red;
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 2em;

}

.text-box {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.text-box input[type="text"] {
  width: 10px;
}



.navbar-primary-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid white;

}

.navbar-primary-menu-items {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.search-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 2em;



}

.search-icon {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
 
  max-height: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
}


.input-field {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

I am trying to build a navbar using flexbox. ( I am total beginner and i don't understand css much, trying out stuff to understand css)
But the problem is, the flex-items as shown in the attached image are

Logo container in the left
A small menu in the middle
A search box div in the right.

The problem i have is,
'A small menu in the middle' div has more space in the left and less space to the right . i.e space from the logo-container to the 'small menu' is more. I don't know how to fix it
What i am trying to do:

use space-between
make sure the space from the middle menu div to the left and  the space from the middle menu div to the right are same.

( The uneven gap i am mentioning is the 'blue colored gap with stripes shown in the image)
Can someone help me understand how to do this?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Possible Duplicate - Align 3 unequal blocks left, center and right

You need to delete the 'nav-content-container' div if you're using space-between for justification.
There should be 3 divs instead of 4 in your 'nav-container' div.
Explore how justify-content works:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.php
